# Dalvik JIT workflow

Tags: android, jit, dalvik, android-source

I am an interested on working on dalvik vm (Android). I am trying to go through the code of JIT to find out the operations performed by it and how it selects the traces. I am unable to follow the code. So I request all to help me by suggesting relevant functions in JIT that performs trace selection and translation

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
git log --grep JIT
```

in the dalvik repository, and looking at the changes and the files changed. That should get you a good idea of where the JIT related code is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found the JIT code but i need to know what are the functions in the JIT code that will be called and the order in which they will be called when an app is being executed.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info.could you please provide me the links to gdb tutorial which would be clear to the amateurs like me.